# Ajuda com codigo em C

Tags: c, algoritmo, codeblocks

No codigo abaixo a intenção era de que criasse um vetor com 10 espaços, dai recebesse 10 valores digitados pelo usuario, verificar se os valores são iguais ou menores que 0 e atribuir o valor 1 nesses casos, porém fiz algo errado que ele faz esse procedimento somente com o primeiro numero inserido, o restante permanece, imagino que o loop esteja errado, mas não entendi como corrigir...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Seu terceiro for (impressão do vetor resultante) está dentro do segundo quando deveria estar após o término do segundo (testar e substituir todos os negativos).

Comment: Também lembrando que se seu array tem o tamanho 10, os indices desse array serão entre 0 a 9, não entre 0 a 10 como no seu código. Alocar um valor na posição 10 pode até não gerar um erro imediato, mas você estará alocando um valor num espaço de memória que não pertence ao array, podendo até sobrescrever um valor sendo utilizado por outra parte do programa.

Answer (score 1):

Como já falaram em outros comentários você está errando no famoso "off-by-one", ou seja, **você está acessando uma posição fora do seu array**.

Quando declaramos `arrays`, o que se coloca entre colchetes é o tamanho do array, não o índice final que você quer.
Ou seja:

```c
int numeros[10];
```

Cria o array chamado `numeros` que consegue armazenar apenas 10 ints, logo os índices vão de 0 a 9.

Os seus `laços for` iteram de 0 a 10, logo você tá acessando 11 posições e não 10 e por consequência acessando uma posição fora do array.

Agora a segunda parte do erro se deve a como você está tentando aplicar o algoritmo proposto e isso se subdivide em 2 erros:

1. De acordo com o algoritmo proposto, você precisa percorrer o
   array uma vez para alterar os valores que sejam `<= 0` e um outro for
   fora desse para então imprimir o resultado, mas você fez `2 laços for`
   aninhados...
2. Além de ter os `2 laços for aninhados`, você utilizou a mesma
   variável de controle nos 2. Então quando o segundo for acaba, i tem
   valor 11 então quando o primeiro for vai verificar se i <= 10, como
   i é 11 ele não executa.

Arrumando o código para atribuir os 1 de forma correta e sem extrapolar o limite do array fica assim:

```c
for( i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
{
    if( X[i] <= 0 )
    {
        X[i] = 1;
    }
}
```

Agora basta que você faça o `laço for` de impressão depois que esse  `laço for` executar totalmente.